# Почему не работает button в переключателе картинок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, веб-дизайн

Работаю со страницей, где есть вот такой странный переключатель картинок(состоит из поля для отображения значения, и кнопок "+" и "-" для регулировки значения).

Вот скрипт, что за него отвечает:

```
$(document).ready(function() { function btnClick(t, stop, togv, togc, add) {
  var $input = t.closest("div.quantity-1").find("input[name='number']");
  var value = parseInt($input.val());
  if (-value*add > -stop*add) {
    value = value + 10* add;
  } else {
    value = stop;
  }
  $input.val(value);
  if (value == togv) 
    $('div.slider').toggleClass(togc);
} 
  $(".minus-button").on("click", function(e) { //обработчик для кнопки .minus-button
    e.preventDefault();
    btnClick($(this), -30, -10, 'slide-4 animation-1', -1); 
  }); 
  $(".plus-button").on("click", function(e) { //обработчик для кнопки .plus-button
    e.preventDefault();
    btnClick($(this), 30, 10, 'slide-1 animation-1', 1);
  });
});
```

И все работает, но картинка просто НЕ ПЕРЕКЛЮЧАЕТСЯ дальше значения +10/-10, все зависает, а переключатель работает как ни в чем не бывало( Я знаю что проблема именно в скрипте! Но другого решения не знаю.

В общем **необходимо чтобы каждый раз при нажатии** на кнопку "+" значение в поле увеличивалось и на странице сразу изменялась фоновая картинка, также и для кнопки "-" но значение не должно превышать +30 и -30 при клике, значение либо увеличиваеться на 10, либо уменьшаеться на 10, картинки добавляються на странице вот такой через css код:

```
main .animation-1
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -100px;
    left: 10px;

    width: 1032px;
    height: 558px;

    background: url(img/start-point-single.png) no-repeat #317199 center;
}
.slide-1
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -100px;
    left: 10px;

    width: 1032px;
    height: 558px;

    background: url(img/anim+10up.gif) no-repeat #317199 center;
}
/* и т.д до slider-12*/
```

Всего 12 картинок и 1 - по умолчанию, при загрузке страницы.
И все это дело отображаеться на странице в контейнере:

```
<div class="slider animation-1"><!--empty zone--></div>
```

Подскажите как решить эту проблемку, или подкиньте правильное решение, кто уже сталкивался с чем-то похожим!!

[image: кнопочный переключатель фоновых картинок на странице]

Comment: скопируй код сюда https://codepen.io/, посмотрим наглядно

Comment: @LevShportak, для этого есть встроенный сниппет

Comment: @LevShportak получается так: https://jsfiddle.net/CyberPaladin/628kdmya/#&togetherjs=K0ULAErymp но так то код работает) там беда с правильным отображением картинок, в них все проблема. Можете картинки свои вставить в css и от туда отталкиваться...

Comment: Я так подумал, что проблема в том что функция btnClick при каждом нажатии выполняеться всегда с одними и теми же параметрами, вот и картинка не меняеться...есть идея зациклить вызов функции btnClick и просто менять параметры на каждом шаге цикла. Кто-то может допилить код по ссылке выше, а то я не шарю синтаксис(